# How to calculate the changes for certain time frames (fixed number of day)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this dataset:

```
index   report_date Australia   Canada  EU
    0   5/1/2020    72175095066 40011932851 1.04973E+11
    1   5/4/2020    71849223125 39255502322 1.0145E+11
    2   5/5/2020    73893204648 39635205124 1.02047E+11
    3   5/6/2020    73101191582 39273264928 1.00353E+11
    4   5/7/2020    73365377495 39476905937 1.00949E+11
    5   5/8/2020    75670286197 40462781517 1.01464E+11
    6   5/11/2020   77624901294 39927082682 1.0043E+11
    7   5/12/2020   75870758117 38297001557 98827026719
    8   5/13/2020   73672696038 37219441466 96116936062
    9   5/14/2020   72988849668 37773087546 95649659017
    10  5/15/2020   73200719701 37832698650 95659747574
    11  5/18/2020   74348548797 37832698650 99470308513
    12  5/19/2020   77342374972 39548652182 98641725934
    13  5/20/2020   77674244724 39771446141 97444823336
    14  5/21/2020   77575079696 39876649653 96886112491
    15  5/22/2020   77127240723 39716531198 97095834171
    16  5/25/2020   79079167679 40790728730 96109194025
    17  5/26/2020   83101752270 41714154711 99487390907
    18  5/27/2020   85535417348 41625243107 1.01877E+11
    19  5/28/2020   84512887208 41405996887 1.03047E+11
    20  5/29/2020   83118710145 40975827882 1.02166E+11
    21  6/1/2020    85381178506 41055477972 1.05438E+11
    22  6/2/2020    86113687012 41502206610 1.09616E+11
    23  6/3/2020    90758154576 42899754234 1.14712E+11
    24  6/4/2020    91897977251 43597908706 1.15293E+11
    25  6/5/2020    94537426844 45507371645 1.20219E+11
    26  6/8/2020    94298812262 47201019703 1.19338E+11
    27  6/9/2020    97980459240 46023582125 1.16425E+11
    28  6/10/2020   94657080614 45065098113 1.14623E+11
    29  6/11/2020   91187286389 43061573758 1.09798E+11
    30  6/12/2020   88719517983 43881975509 1.11402E+11
    31  6/15/2020   87488604108 44671584583 1.11624E+11
```

How could I calculate the changes for 5 Days, 1 month?

I've got an idea using df.shift but there will be timing errors as there is no data for weekends. I hope to create a new column for 5 days and another new column for 1 month.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a question it is better to show what research you have done into your problem and post any code or errors if it applies. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Take a look at [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) if you're manipulating a CSV or other related dataset. Also, look into [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) since you're working with time frames.